# The "detectseparation" package. How to interpret its results?

Tags: r, logistic, multiple-regression, maximum-likelihood, reporting

I am running a logistic regression on financial data of several companies. The dependent variable is the company to be a smoother (binary variable: 0, 1), and there are several independent variables: company age, company size, number of board meetings, etc. I tried to run a glm that detect any complete separation in this model through the R-package "detectseparation." The code in R was:

```
detect<-glm(formula=smth~0+Big4+age+lev+assets_log+committee+PctIndependentDirectors+meetings+boardsize+afe+value_log+revgrowth_log,data=data2,family = binomial("logit"),method = "detect_separation")
```

the result was:
[image]

We can see that there is always 0 next to each IV. What does 0 mean?
How about -inf and +inf?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it says in the printout, these values indicate existence of the maximum likelihood estimates. 0 means they are finite (i.e. no complete separation), whereas infinite values are for completely separated predictors (0 for `-Inf` and 1 for `Inf` respectively).

You should use the standard `glm` methods like `summary` and `anova` to extract parameter estimates and inferences - all this object's `print` shows you right now is that there don't seem to be any complete separation issues.